c++ ostream of object implicitly-convertible to string_view does not compile
I have a string-like class that is implicitly convertible to string_view.  This works in almost all cases, but not for ostream inserters, where I need to explicitly write an ostream inserter for my class.  Equivalent case for an object convertible to an int does work for ostream.
I am guessing the reason is that string_view (and hence the ostream inserter) are templates, but can someone explain in more detail why this fails to compile?
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>

struct I {
    operator int() const { return 4; }
};
struct S {
    operator std::string_view() const { return "I am an S"; }
};

int main() {
    I i;
    S s;
    std::cout << i;  // Works
    std::cout << s;  // Doesn't
}

See Godbolt

Always post complete error along with your question.

Just use cout << static_cast<string_view>(s);

Another instance of: Why does the implicit type conversion not work in template deduction?. Also Cannot std::cout an implicitly converted std::string

Adding the missing colon, and the remaining error is a failure to find a candidate match for cout << s.

"I am guessing the reason is that string_view..." This isn't limited to string_view. You can change string_view to std::string and same error will be generated.

One solution is of course to add an operator<< for S that does the casting for you. (Or just writes the text, if that is the only use for the conversion).

Thanks to semi-anonymous @user12002570 whose stack overflow search skills are clearly better than mine.  I did try to find other similar questions, I promise!
Root cause as mentioned in the referenced answers is that the collection of potential overloads (including instantiations of templates using type deduction) happens first, then the "best" overload is selected which is when conversion operators are considered.  S cannot be deduced to operator<<(basic_string_view<char<) so that template is not included in the overload set.

@Greg You're welcome :)
